# Solving an equation using the floor function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, numerical-methods

Let $x,a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

I would like to know for what values of $a$, $b$, and $c$:

$$
   \lfloor x^2 \rfloor
       = \lfloor a x^2 +b x + c \rfloor
$$

Comment: What values of $x$ should satisfy this? All of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: We could restrict the domain. Say, $x \in [-2, 2]$.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if this should be true for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the left hand side can never be negative. Furthermore, $a x^2 + b x + c$ can have no real zeros (except possibly $x = 0$), as at a zero left and right sides won't agree. In particular, the discriminant $b^2 - 4 a c \le 0$. If $a > 1$,  eventually $a x^2$ is large enough to make $a x^2 + b x + c > x^2 + 1$, both sides can't agree.

As you see, you can discard potential values for the coefficients by a case by case analysis. There might be a cleaner way...